# React app works on local but doesn't work on Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting

I have done a react app using firebase db. I deployed on firebase last week and I closed. Yesterday I tried again, and
I get this error:

[image]

> Site Not Found
>
> Why am I seeing this?
>
> There are a few potential reasons:
>
> 1. You haven't deployed an app yet.
> 2. You may have deployed an empty directory.
> 3. This is a custom domain, but we haven't finished setting it up yet.

Also, It works when I run `npm run start`  I think. I have done -`firebase init` command correctly and after run - `npm run build` after run `firebase deploy`.

Firebase json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried that firstly run npm run build after run firebase init. I chose no the owerwritte choice. Doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vite, you could try to test if your build works locally by doing an "`npm run preview`"/"`npx vite preview`" and changing the value of the `hosting.public` key from "`build`" to "`dist`".

Comment: I dont use Vite